# Interpolate a rectangular surface with given edges

Tags: surfaces, interpolation

I need to interpolate a surface by filling a rectangular hole. The height values of the edges are given.

[image]

I would like to fill the rectangular surface patch by somehow interpolating the edge values. I already tried bilinear interpolation but the result wasnt very good.

Do you know any fast way to interpolate the hole? The best way would be a function $f(x,y) : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ that assigns a height value for every point of the surface.

Comment: Look up transfinite interpolation.

Comment: i just looked up transfinite interpolation and found this website: http://www.ann.jussieu.fr/perronnet/transfini/transfini.html. this is exactly what i did before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $f_0(y)$ the values on the segment $\{0\}\times[0,1]$, $f_1(y)$ the values on $\{1\}\times [0,1]$, and similarly $g_0(x)$ and $g_1(x)$.

A continuous function interpolating them is
$$
\frac{[(1-x)f_0(y) + xf_1(y)]y(1-y) + [(1-y)g_0(x) + yg_1(x)]x(1-x)}{x(1-x) + y(1-y)}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is a really simple way to interpolate the values. Is there a name for this method? I looks like nevilles algorithm with 2 variables.

Comment: just invented it on the moment. I don't know if it has a name..

Comment: It at least resembles the bilinear case of transfinite interpolation.